# How reload a web page only once and avoid infinite reloading using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying display some user information(Name, DOB, Gender etc.) and 2 pdf documents.

```
app.controller('welcomeController',[ '$scope', '$http', '$window',  function($scope, $http, $window)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $http.post('recordforid', $scope.id ).success(function(response)
        {
            $scope.res=response;
            $http.post('viewDoc', $scope.id).success(function(re){
                $scope.doc = re;
            }).error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    }, 2000);
    $window.location.reload();
    $route.reload();
    location.reload();
    $scope.Back = function(){
        $location.url('/showdetailsforuser/'+ $scope.res.userId);
    }
}]);
```

The problem I'm facing is- I'm uploading 2 documents in registration page and displaying the documents immediately in the next page. I'm storing the files in a project folder of eclipse(project is locally stored). So that folder will not be updated until I refresh the webpage. I used a timeout() function with a delay of 2 seconds but it is not working all the time. I want to refresh the page once or twice. For this I tried with $window.location.reload(), $route.reload(), location.reload(). All are refreshing the page for infinite times. I placed them outside timeout function too but same problem. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why would using `setTimeout` stop anything be updated until you refresh the page? It stops things happening for a number of milliseconds. Why are you trying to delay anything?

Comment: If I use an alert, delay is happening and documents are displaying. So I'm using timeout() as an alternative.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the page? You can put the logic of showing the right page in the call back function of HTTP post right?